# Get source code of Amazon Page through Amazon API

Tags: python, amazon-product-api

I'm working on a small project and I'm having trouble with the Amazon API.
Specifically, I can't find a way to get the source code of an entire page with multiple products.

I already tried some solutions based on various answers for somewhat related questions, but couldn't find anything working for me.
Does someone have any idea if this is feasible?

Comment: Could you clarify more on what you are attempting to do, and share the code you have so far?  See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), on how to update your question.  My assumption is that you're looking to do some sort of webscraping, and the answer is likely that most of the page is dynamically generated with JS, so you would need to actually load the page in a browser with Selenium and then do whatever you're trying to do.